# React - pass state to template rendered with dangerouslysetHTML

Tags: reactjs, flask-restful

In my app, I am using React at Frontend and Flask at backend.

Some pages render static content, for which I'm using Jinja2 templates directly from backend.

So, at Frontend, I get my template from Flask as a response object and inject it using `dangerouslysetHTML`, like so:

**seeds.py**

```
@seeds_bp.route('/seeds/<user_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def seeds(user_id):
    user = User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first()
    template = render_template('seeds.html',items=items)
    response_object = {
                    'status': 'success',
                    'data': [{"content": template}]
    return jsonify(response_object), 200
```

and after getting the data:

**Seeds.jsx**

```
    render(){
      const {userId} = this.props
      var seeds_html = this.state.seeds_template;
      var seeds_template = { __html: seeds_html };
      return (
         <div id="parent">
         <h1 className="title is-1"><font color="#C86428">Seeds</font></h1>
          <hr/><br/>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={seeds_template}/>
        </div>
      );       
    }
  }
```

The catch is **my rendered html has redirects requiring user_id as well** in it, to which I have no access, so I can't pass my 'user_id' state to my template:

**seeds.html**

```
<form action="{{ url_for('menus.edit_menu', items=items, user_id=user_id) }}" method="post">
```

Is there an out of the box method or any other customized function so I can pass this 'user_id' state to template rendered via `dangerouslysetHTML`?

Comment: Where is `menu_html` coming from?

Comment: That’s was a typo sorry. Fixed

Comment: Could you change the variable name; e.g. `user_id=_user_id` then you could do `.replace('_user_id', 'actualValue')` before you inject into the html?

Comment: check this -> https://es.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml I think is because your var name

Comment: I could, sure. You can give me a full answer with that approach if you will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `String.replace()` to inject variables into your template which is then injected into your `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. Something like this:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('menus.edit_menu', items=items, user_id=_user_id) }}" method="post">
```

Then:

```
render() {
  const { userId } = this.props;
  const seedsHtml = this.state.seeds_template;
  const template = { __html: seedsHtml.replace("_user_id", userId) };  
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template} />;
}
```